# Set default value in <select> with angular ng-options maybe using ng-init

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, ng-options, ng-init

I have this in html

```
<select ng-model="inventory.condition"
        ng-init="inventory.condition = con"
        ng-options="con.name for con in conditions"
    <option >-- choose condition --</option>
</select>
{{inventory.condition}}
```

On js angular controler:

```
$scope.conditions = [
        {"name":"New","id":101},
        {"name":"Used","id":102},
        {"name":"Like new","id":103},
        {"name":"Not Working","id":104}
] 
$scope.inventory.condition = {"name":"Used","id":102};
```

The SELECT populate works fine, and if I select a item on list it set ng-model correctly and Htlm displays correctly the model selected (I want to get the complete model selected, not only the "id" value), but I can't set the default value when build the list.

The idea is receive a model (js object) that contains the default value (what really coming from a html request from a WS that is previously persisted on DB) and select the default item with the value from model, and if user selects a new item, it can changes the same model (what I will update/persist again later).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is that `$scope.inventory.condition` must be `$scope.conditions` array element, and two objects are equal only when they are the same object. So you can't just set `$scope.inventory.condition = {"name":"Used","id":102};`: event though `{"name":"Used","id":102}` looks like the second value of array, in reality they are not equal, so Angular will not set it as default value.

You need to set model value like this:

```
$scope.conditions = [
    {"name":"New","id":101},
    {"name":"Used","id":102},
    {"name":"Like new","id":103},
    {"name":"Not Working","id":104}
];
$scope.inventory.condition = $scope.conditions[1];
```

Comment: Ohhh.. thank you @dfsq. You're absolutely right, so just to complete my finally solution I use a $filter to get the correct element from $scope.conditions array and set it to the ng-model. I'm sure there's other ways to locate it, but if there's problem with this let me know, Thanks again:
`$scope.inventory.condition = $filter('filter')($scope.conditions, {id: $scope.inventory.condition.id}, true)[0];`